# positioning in IE7 slightly off (like 10px top and right)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, positioning

I have a certain problem and searched through a lot of questions to find a solution but I just can not seem to fix it. The problem is as following:

There is the main "wrapper" div on the page (for centering reasons), and inside this is some text, images and a number of includes (footer, header etc.). The images are using "position: absolute" and using the CSS "top" and "left" property to offset them. However, Firefox and Internet Explorer 7 seem to start their offset from a different point, meaning the most of the images are just about 10px lower and 10px more to the right in IE7

What I've done to make sure;
    - validated my html with the W3C validator (fixed everything)
    - tried to replace position:absolute; with some position:relative; 
    - The position of the wrapper has been set as position:relative;
    - would rather not want to work with a a specific stylesheet just for IE7 (so didn't try that) 
    - PS: used meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" to let my IE8 browser shows my project like it was in IE7

I'm really hoping you could help me out! Thanks in advance and hereby i'm giving the corresponding HTML and CSS

HTML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>

 <title>
 Document Title 
 </title>

 <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="includes/mainmenu/Mainmenustyle.css"/>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="includes/header_main/header_mainstyle.css"/>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="includes/footer_main/footer_mainstyle.css"/>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="Homepagestyle.css"/>

 </head>

 <body>

 <div id="bg"></div>
 <div id="wrapper">

 <div>
 <!--#include virtual="includes/mainmenu/mainmenu.html" -->
 </div>

 <div>
 <!--#include virtual="includes/header_main/header_main.html" -->
 </div>

 <div id="about_us" class="about_us">
 <p>Some text.</p></div>

 <a href="portfolio/graphic/fotoanne.shtml" class="rollover" title="FotoAnne"><span class="displace"></span></a>

 <div id="aboutgreyhorsenl_title" class="aboutgreyhorsenl_title">
 <img src="images/aboutnl_image.png" alt="About Greyhorse"/></div>


 <div>
 <!--#include virtual="includes/footer_main/footer_main.html" -->
 </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
margin:10px auto;
width:1100px;
}

#bg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 614px; 
   position: absolute;
   top: 93px;
   left: 0;
   background-image: url(images/stripe.png);
   background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
   background-attachment: scroll;
} 

body {
background-image:url(images/Background_Homepage.png);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: top;
font-family: arial;
color: #111111;
font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px/16=0.75 em */
word-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 175%;
}

.about_us {
display: block;
width: 420px;
height: 12px;
position: absolute;
left:290px;
top:-110px;
}

.aboutgreyhorsenl_title {
position: absolute;
top: 280px;
left: 400px;
}

a.rollover {
display: block;
width: 155px;
height: 115px;
text-decoration: none;
background: url("images/FotoAnne_thumbnail.png");
position: absolute;
left:735px;
top:-100px;
}

a.rollover:hover {
background-position: 775px 0;
}

.displace {
position: absolute;
left:287px;
top:-205px;
}
```

Thanks in advance again for anyone who could help me out!

Comment: I tried to delete some of the elements one by one to see if there were any changes when doing so. Deleted the includes (no effect) than the wrapper (no effect) than the div id="bg" used for a second bg (no effect) and eventually ended up deleting the .body properties but this also didn't make any changes. Most of the images are still a little bit (like 10, 15px) off

Comment: Due to the XML-Prolog (`<?xml ...`) your document is in quirks mode in IE7. Does it help if you remove it and work in standards mode?

Comment: oh I did not even notice i still had the XML-Prolog there, thanks for that. Even so, when I removed it, it unfortunately  didn't solve my problem...

Comment: Allright, I think I have found a partial solution although it's more a recommendation for myself. I've found that it's best to avoid absolute positioning unless I have everything just right and controlled. I'm better of with some floats to eventually move them into place with margins, paddings etc. 

Correct me if I'm wrong, i'm still kind of a newbie.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Avoiding absolute positioning is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

the style.css file from the html5boilerplate will make all browsers have the same 'default' settings.. adding this css file to your site (as the first one to be loaded), might fix the issue.

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but it didn't work unfortunately. I browsed through the site though and saw that they are now using a .css file called NORMALIZE.CSS to retains useful browser defaults. Maybe I should try that one?